# using multiple events with the same function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making attempts to clean up my code. Just wondering if there's a way to write this code better? I've added a snippet of my code below:

```
$('.popUp-block').on("click",function() {
    $('.protect-field-container').removeClass('is-displayed');
    $(this).closest('.protect-field-container').addClass('is-displayed');
});

$('.popUp-block').hover(function() {
    $('.protect-field-container').removeClass('is-displayed');
    $(this).closest('.protect-field-container').addClass('is-displayed');
});

$('.popUp-block').focusout(function() {
    $('.protect-field-container').removeClass('is-displayed');
});

$('.popUp-block').on("mouseout", function() {
    $('.protect-field-container').removeClass('is-displayed');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In simple way, you can do it with [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$('.popUp-block').on("click mouseover",function() {
  $('.protect-field-container').removeClass('is-displayed');
  $(this).closest('.protect-field-container').addClass('is-displayed');
});

$('.popUp-block').on("mouseout focusout", function() {
  $('.protect-field-container').removeClass('is-displayed');
});
```

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> ***One or more space-separated event types*** and optional namespaces, such as `"click"` or `"keydown.myPlugin"`.